# How to prevent powered armor from letting people carry bigger guns?

Tags: science-based, warfare, armors

Oh yes, personal powered armors, such as MJOLNIR, are a staple of sci-fi. A sci-fi that disguises itself as fantasy needs to have some for the knights!

But, there is one thing I don't want to let it do, that is increasing encumbrance. If powered armor allows people to wield and shoot a Barret M82 like it was nothing, the whole point of finally letting armor catch up to firepower is lost.

**So, powered armor can increase punching strength but won't allow you to carry that weight. Why?**

Comment: Soldiers can already carry the M82 fairly easily and can fire it from the prone position.  Are you trying to make power armour-wearing soldiers less able to carry items than everyday soldiers, or are you wanting to stop them firing from a standing unsupported position, or both?

Comment: pretty sure lifting and punching use different bio mechanism or power or whatever it really called as. here a good [link](https://expertboxing.com/why-lifting-weights-wont-increase-punching-power) regarding it.

Comment: The point of the powered armor is that it can carry the weight of all that armor. If it didnt carry that extra armor you'll be carrying a gun far too big for its purpose and get killed just as easily by small-arms. So the extra encumbrance is all taken by the armor. Also we dont build tanks like the Mauser anymore because the loss of speed and maneuverability is more problematic than the extra armor can compensate for. So the extra weaponry and ammo would be too limiting for the power armor.

Comment: Thing is, effective protection weighs much, much, much more than the bigger gun. A breastplate that can withstand the shot of a M82 is heavier than the M82 itself - the sci-fi powered armor is *not* a way of letting armor catch up to firepower unless you have extremely light unobtanium armor e.g. personal force fields that's *not* powered.

Comment: (Not a real answer) - The fingers on the armor are too big to fit in the trigger guard of the gun.  (Yeah, yeah, so just make guns with bigger trigger guards - I said it wasn't a real answer.)

Comment: @LiJun: Lifting and punching use different muscles and therefore you can develop a suit that assists with one but not the other. But that doesn't provide a justification why you wouldn't be able develop a suit that can wield bigger guns _instead of_ (or in addition to) increasing punching power. OP is working on the assumption that people will want to wield bigger guns and is looking for a way to prevent that even if they tried to.

Comment: @Peteris: You're not wrong but you're not accounting for significant improvements in technology. Think about what kevlar did for the weight of a bulletproof vest. I'm not saying that a kevlar easily stops a Barret M82, but similar improvements can be discovered in regards to armor that protects against larger calibers, which mostly negates your "effective protection weighs much, much, much more than the bigger gun" point (once discovered) If we're already dealing with a society that uses power armor, other advancements can also have been made.

Comment: Do M82 have wheels?

Comment: @Flater well i just try to tell Op regarding the statement "So, powered armor can increase punching strength but won't allow you to carry that weight. Why?" in the question, since not only it use different muscle, developing muscle for lifting heavy weight actually has bad side effect for punching strength. but i dont know how different power armor work is.

Comment: Give it really tiny fingers.

Comment: @LiJun: OP isn't asking why a specific design of power armor can't lift heavy weaponry, OP is asking why you can't create a power armor that does so when you already have the ability to create power armor to punch harder. Using the exact same technology to build a punching power armor, you can create a lifting armor. The armors may be constructed differently but any civilization that can make one therefore inherently has the technology to make the other.

Comment: @Flater i dont know...it sounds like OP want both punching strength and lifting strength for the power armor, to me. heck i dont even understand why OP want punching strength or bring it up in its question, since it sound like this is for battle rather than for sport or competition. it more practical to use melee weapon if want to engage in melee, if the power armor cant repair themselves or get dent due to the punch, it can break something regarding the power armor engine or machine, and i believe the person can get a risk to stuck there or crush some of the body parts especially the limbs.

Comment: You can't. Even without power armor, there are still hand-held antitank weapons capable of punching through a couple of feet of steel plate. No worn armor will ever withstand even all portable weapons.

Answer (score 31):

**You can't**

The whole point of power armour is to carry more and carrying more means carrying bigger guns and if you had power armour, people would make bigger guns for them to carry.

Weapons soldiers use is limited by their ability to carry it around. Bigger weapons require a mobile weapon platform (ie wheels). Power armour is just another mobile weapon platform. It's stronger so can carry more and has more mass thus can handle more recoil from bigger weapons.

Any reason you come up with will have to be wishy washy such as a mega death cannon doesn't look as cool as a giant ass sword

There is no physical reason for power armour not to have bigger guns and it would defy logic not to give them bigger guns.

Comment: Half the point.  The other half is to have more armor that prevents other people from injuring or killing you with their bigger guns.

Comment: @Mary Carry more also means carry more armour. It's powered to carry more both guns and armour.

Comment: This answer gets to the raw truth, but I would add that from a practicality standpoint, just being able to carry and shoot a Barrett M82 is only half of the equation- being able to carry enough ammunition to do anything *useful* with it is another matter entirely. Look up just how big those rounds and magazines are. Even if you can handle the extra weight, carrying a full combat load (240+) rounds of .50BMG loaded into 10-round magazines adds a prohibitive amount of bulk to your kit. The main reason most militaries use 5.56 rifles rather than 7.62 is to reduce the weight and bulk of *ammo*.

Answer (score 29):

$Strength \propto \frac{1}{Speed}$

Also known as "Speed versus Torque".

Power armour loaded to slightly more than the typical soldier's kit allows you to sprint at high speeds without getting tired, leap 10 feet into the air, and punch like a charging bull.

Power armour can *also* let you carry a metric ton of weight (e.g. a 1979 Volkswagen Beetle).  But, not **both** at the **same time**.

Think about it this way: a car can zoom along at 150mph, or it can drag a heavy trailer up a hill.  It *can't* drag a heavy trailer up a hill at 150mph.  The former requires a High Gear setting (high speed, low torque), the latter requires a Low Gear setting (low speed, high torque)

So too with your Power Armour.  If the techs back at base have set it up for pure strength, then you have *pure* strength.  The Force behind your punch is going to be on par with a freight train - *if* you can hit something.  You'll be moving slowly enough that most people can dodge: $Power = \frac {Force*Distance}{Time}$.  You can *push* really hard, and apply tons of **pressure**, but not *fast* enough to be worthwhile as a punch.

Similarly, you could probably use a [Howitzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howitzer) like a rifle - but, you can't aim it fast enough to track most moving targets close-up.  And, at range, you might as well just put it down and use it *normally*.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why destroyers where preferred for naval fire support on D-Day, they had the battleships, but a destroyer gun could get on target on a tank or bunker far faster than a battleship could, and still provide sufficient damage. You want the lightest gun that is big enough.

Comment: Yes, this is why we can't design cars that both go faster than people and carry heavier loads.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Yes, this is why trucks go slower than sports cars.  I mean, you *could* scale it all up, but then you don't have Power Armour, you have a tank or a mech.

Comment: You have a mech when the operator's joints are no longer coaxial with the armour's. Powered exoskeletons already exist that are strong and fast enough to meet the OP's requirements, saying you can't build something which meets the requirement is like saying you can't make a car that goes faster than you can run and can carry more than you can.

Answer (score 10):

**It's not feasible**

> If powered armor allows people to wield and shoot a Barret M82 like it
> was nothing, the whole point of finally letting armor catch up to
> firepower is lost.

There is a quote: "If it works, it's already obsolete". It's inevitable that people would try to use find something to counteract the counteraction. For example, There is methods to block adblockers that blocks ad that blocks adblockers.

**Unless...**

The old solution to the problem just isn't available. Maybe at some point the size of the weapon would need to grow in size exponentially to have enough power to destroy the armor that gets carrying capacity linearly.

For example (all numbers completely imaginary):
In the beginning in that case a armour would be destroyed by a 5kg gun, but allow for carrying 30kg. Later it would need a 10kg gun to be damaged, but only allow for 35kg extra capacity. Eventually these two points meets at, for example 100kg.The next iteration of armor would need a 200kg weapon to be damaged, but only allow for 110kg carrying capacity.

The guns would still get absurdly more powerful, but not enough to actually be useful against an opponent with a similar armor.

*Or maybe the armor just happens to have some other pseudo-magical boons that counteract the weapons.*

Answer (score 8):

**FORCE FIELDS:**
All that armor is nice, but it's real virtue is in being a surface that conducts energy for personal energy fields that foil all those heavy weapons. These fields conform to the user's armor suit, and they are most vulnerable to contact with other armor, since the fields interact. So lasers refract, plasma scatters, projectile weapons are deflected, or bounce off, or need to hit incredibly hard, yet a fellow suited warrior with a conductive melee weapon attached to their suit can cut through it.

If the field is somehow psychic, even better - drone weapons and robots can't use them, and psychic power doesn't need a portable nuclear reactor.

That's not to say all those weapons don't work, or are ineffective. I don't think you can stop bigger guns, but they would need to be MUCH bigger to compete with force fields. The real goal isn't to take away the cool toys, but to bring back the good old fun ones - fists, swords, axes, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The power provided by the armour is equal to the power needed to move said armour. In this case wearer still can't transport anything heavy, but they can deliver a good punch - high mass means high kinetic energy.

This idea was partially used in Fallout 1, where weight if the armour is higher than the bonus it provides - https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Power_armor_(Fallout). Though, strength stat increase meant being able to hold heavy weapons.

Answer (score 5):

While some answers have delved into the mechanics of powered armour (speed vs torque, the effects on joints and so on), there are other consideratons which might come into play.

1. Logistics. You might not want to have a wide range of weapons, or single large overpowered weapons, but rather use the armour to allow the soldier to carry more of their existing ammunition and equipment. A typical loadout today is 10 X 30 round magazines for an M-4 carabine. What if the armour allowed you to carry 30 magazines, plus 3 days MRE's, 10l of water and other equipment? The purpose of the armour isn't to make a super soldier, but to enhance the ordinary soldier's ability to remain active in the field before linking up to the logistic support network.

[image]

*A suit that lets you carry this makes more sense*

2. Much larger weapons *are* possible, but the suit becomes a vehicle rather than armour. A HMG or automatic cannnon might be possible to mount on a suit, but you cannot fire it like a rifle, the offset torque will throw off aim, set up unwanted stresses and failure modes etc. Some sort of carriage and stabilization mechanism will be needed, which increases the size and complexity of the suit. Robot platforms with full stabilization make far more sense, since they can fire on the move.

[image]

*OK, we're going to squeeze in through the basement window and then find the tunnel entrance....*

3. Reality ensues. Soldiers already can carry extremely powerful weapons without any sort of augmentation today. A Javalin ATGM allows a soldier to attack a tank or even hovering helicopter with confidence at a range of 2500m or more. A soldier with a standard underbarrel grenade launcher can take out lightly armoured vehicles and fortifications at a range of 400m, and future "guided" grenades like the "Pike" can extend this to over 1000m. No amount of personal body armour will protect you if a soldier is firing something like a Javalin, and if powered armour becomes common, then anti armour weapons will become common as a counter-measure. That being the case, simple exo skeletons to allow more load carrying (see point 1) make far more sense

[image]

*I'll see your armour and raise you a missile*

Or, you could always issue some of these instead

[image]

Answer (score 2):

JOINTS!

If you carry more weight, when you try to jump, the added weight will destroy the complex  wired teflon joints.

If you try to move with more weight, the effective range is reduced, after all, the fuel cells can only provide this much juice.

Shooting a barret is done stationary.
Leaping with 30 kgs more, will stress the knee and ankle joinst past the safe limit. Could be a moment of tension in your story.

*If I carry a bigger gun but discard the rations.. maybe I can make it before I die of dehidration.*

Comment: An exoskeleton that can't even carry extra 30kg gun is kind of useless - every ordinary soldier is expected to carry 30kg+ on patrol, see https://www.quora.com/What-weight-do-marines-carry-in-a-combat-load .

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly the lack of real world experience of most game designers that causes what you see in games, which is why I seldom play them. Given my experience as a paramilitary contractor, i cringe at the sight on how wrong they get it. in one movie with soldiers in Science fiction, i cringed as I watched them do over 20 things that you just never do on the field.

I personally believe that manned platforms like power armor simply wouldn't be made, and instead humanoid war droids would be deployed instead. The biggest solution to MJOLNIR killing a normal human is to make the platform unmanned from the get go, and mass produce those. a battledroid can be mass produced whereas a human takes two decades to mature, and is irreplaceable. when a human dies, you're never getting him back---not even with cloning.

and to answer the question, humans wouldn't carry that weight, because they would never have the need to. Just send in your MJOLNIR based killers robots against the covenant and keep your virtually never ending flow of reinforcements coming against the covenant. superior technology or not, with an endless flow of reinforcements, the covenant would soon find their holy war untenable if not outright unwinnable in a period of a year to 17 months by my estimates. And it's how it would actually be.

generally, stories like halo usually have the Spartans to give something the audience could relate to, but it's far from how such a conflict would actually be fought. The UNSC would quickly phase out manned assets and start a crash program to replace them with unmanned versions the first battle things go south, and start investing in unmanned drones and warships like there is no tomorrow. Although the Spartan IIs would be in the picture, they would become the main bodies of drones based on their suits, and operate from semi-unmanned warships.

you halo fans may call me out on the above, but it's how in real life it'd go in all likelihood. in spite of of being outclassed in technology, the UNSC, once they go the unmanned route would crush the covenant under the weight of endless numbers.

as a matter of fact, that's how the Red army and the armies of the allies defeated the Axis powers in WWII: Numbers.

and with Halo and other games, it's just a story, and somebody's opinion. It's an opinion based best guess of what somebody thinks will work.

Comment: While I agree on your conclusion, from the point of view of a government or organization, humans may be morally irreplaceable and whatnot, but they are *actually* easily replaceable (by another one) and they come free - you don't have to pay to *build* them, while every unit of unmaned robo-soldiers is $1.5 billion a piece. An infinite number of droids requires an infinite budget. That's why the US Air Force does not have 5,000 F-22 fighters.

Comment: Thats all true, but there are countless ways to make it make sense. Armours powered by psychic abilities, expandable humans that are cheaper  in a grim dark future, clones and all kinds of other sience fiction stuff. So the real world doesn't really apply because most of the time it's a different or alternate world.

Comment: Actually, there's no point in making humanoid robots at that point. A remote-controlled quadcopter with a rocket launcher will probably do the job just as well and be much cheaper while retaining the reliability and smartiness of humans. On a side note, don't forget the fi in sci-fi. It has to be an interesting story/game.

Comment: Its a story-telling thing. A story about droney the drone just isnt as interesting as a human (modified as he may be) battling the odds and simultaneously being superior. This is why 100% of all science fiction is wrong. Especially the hard science fiction. But you know what? Its actually FUN when its wrong, as long as its consistent with itself.

Comment: @AmiralPatate Depends on the purpose: as a peacekeeping force, a quadcopter murderbot is a lot less likely to be able to reassure and calm the civilian populace than a humanoid robot or, even better, a human in power armour.  Your drones would be reminiscent of biblical angels:  ***"B̬̜̰̱̣ͅe͏̩̦͕̯̮͎ ̳̩̬̯̼̩N̹̺̮̺͠ͅo̙̪̝̼͈̩͇̕t̢ ͖͓̭͡A̯͇̩̟̱ͅf̻rà̹̗̫͚i̵̜d҉̫̞"*** *{Panicked Screaming Ensues}* ***"I̵͈̹̟̦̹ ̮̜̣̬S̰̜̪̟ạ̴̥͚̤͍i͕d̯̥̤̰͉̕ͅ,̵̣͙͉ ̘̙́B̶̯̝̦ḛ̺͚̥͖̣͝ ̝̜͚̹̰̖N̼̤̬̖͟o̩͉t͙ A̭̬͙̻f̞̰r͈͚̬̥͜a̖͓ị̬̩͠d͚͎̩̺̙͇͇͢!̝̯͎͕̗"*** *{Even more Panicked Screaming takes place}*

Comment: @Chronocidal I agree, if you are worried about public outlook, I think any machine is going to be a hard sale regardless.

Comment: @Rekesoft: No, the reason the US doesn't have 5000 F-22 fighters is that it doesn't need 5000. (Arguably it doesn't need any, but that's a different issue.)  You also fail to appreciate manufacturing economics.  Most of the cost of things is R&D: it may cost umpteen billion to design & build the FIRST F-22, CPU, or battle droid, but then the incremental cost of building more drops pretty quickly.

Comment: @Demigan I beg to differ. The Bolo Franchise is a perfect example where unmanned machines are the main characters of the story. Frankly, this is a unexplored territory with lots of potential using machines as characters. And it's people mostly cutting corners in a story either because they are on a time crunch, or they just want a story published. They call it fiction because most of the time, it's not grounded in reality.

the Bolo series, albeit fanciful, is closer to how a future war against aliens would actually be IRL.

Comment: @Mr.Anderson even though they are tanks, the tanks are as you say characters. The thing keeping them interesting is their human reactions and abilities, which again is against the grain of hard science fiction. But you are right, as long as it has those characteristics that allow us feeble humans to identify with them then you can have stories with Droney the drone, or any other species or objects. Cortana is an often loved character even though she's "been" a spaceship, a powered armor, a ring of Galactic destruction and more.

Comment: While machine learning is making great strides today, we are nowhere near any reasonable level of "improvise, adapt, overcome" in a way that a droid can autonomously function as an equivalent to a human being. Without autonomy, you're just opening yourself up to signal jammers, which then make a really good case for power armor that can be autonomously operated. You're hitting on the Robocop (especially the 2014 remake) plotline, where an automated droid _sounds_ better but really, really isn't without perfectly "human" AI. [..]

Comment: [..] If "no loss of life" was the primary contributor to succesfully waging war, no one would currently ever fight an offensive war. It sounds nice but it simply doesn't follow suit without needing to rewrite civilization and human nature to its very core.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative: conventional weapons have simply changed.

Around the time of world war II all factions asked themselves the question of what caliber their weapons would need to be, and all 3 came around to the same conclusions for each caliber and their use. This because each caliber had a purpose in how powerful they needed to be at different ranges.

With the introduction of power armor we can also assume that metamaterials are introduced. If you can synthesize the strongest spidersilk available to spiders you can make incredible armor protection, and this is just one layer of your power armor. Graphene doped products, Diameme(1), converting the bullet impact into pressure inside a layer etc could all help make these armors extremely resiliant while weapons might still be prohibatively expensive. A railgun for example has problems at the end of the barrel where the forces expelling the projectile blast bits of the rail away with each shot, needing replacement soon.

The end result is that the conventional weapon is still an explosive charge meant to launch a bullet, but with a larger base caliber to wear down power armor and chip pieces away, bruising the internal structure until finally the armor or occupant fails. So your soldiers do carry a machinegun version of an M82, but are still less able to kill their opponents.

1:  https://www.freerepublic.com/focus/f-news/3617263/posts

Answer (score 1):

**Because the weight limit is still the person**

It's kind of funny you mention MJOLNIR armor in your question, as HALO lore very specifically ties down the armor to SPARTAN soldiers because the armor *literally will kill a normal human if they attempt to wear it*. You can increase the power of armor, sure, but ultimately, there's a human inside that armor, which means that all the armor's weight is focused on the human. So, even if it can have a hydraulic punch that can dent a foot of steel, it still can't pick up significant weights or handle massive recoil without putting too much stress on the human wearing it.

It will probably still allow for the casual use of the M82 sniper rifle, but fortunately futuristic super-alloys is also a staple of sci-fi, so you can make the armor out of that and explain that they are now completely bulletproof.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe carrying stuff depletes the armor's batteries faster...

Comment: This is simply not correct.  You can design the armor as a powered exoskeleton, so that it puts as little force on the human as say operating large earthmoving equipment.

Comment: @jamesqf Its not really armor at that point though, is it? Might as well be a mini-mech. And while mini-mechs are awesome, there is somehow a distinction between mini-mechs and powered armor in soft sci-fi.

Comment: @Halfthawed Insert running gag in Saint's Row IV where NPCs and Playa are arguing about whether the mech that Playa finds is a robot or power armor, until Playa comes across actual power armor in the last mission of the game.

Comment: @Mephistopheles The battery thing would actually be a legitimate answer.

Comment: @Halfthawed: What you choose to call something is at best nothing but marketing.  Are you basing your answer on game rules, or engineering?

Comment: @jamesqf Given that the OP described this as 'sci-fi that disguises itself as fantasy', I'm not basing this answer on the hardest of engineering concepts. It is true that the strain on a user is something that needs to be addressed when building power armor, so using that concept to explain limitation is acceptable in soft sci-fi.

Answer (score 1):

In another question it was asked why power armour wasn't feasible. It's because firepower is incredibly high, making power armour too expensive and easily damaged to be viable.

To offset this, the power armour might have added several layers of protection. All the weight added to it does make a "normal" movement difficult to stop and thus incredibly powerful. A punch is something you don't want happening to you or equipment you own. Downside is that the motors are taxed to the max thanks to the weight. Any additional weight starts slowing it down, making only light and normal weapons feasible. If heavier weapons are carried, the armour gets so slow It's impractical or simply stops to function.
Finally, the armour is still strong despite being at it's maximum power thanksto the weight. Possibly in the field the armour often accidentally crushes the weapons when the soldiers are in tense situations and they squeeze their weapons. This makes heavy weapons too risky to wield as they present a more hefty investment. Add to this that soldiers are often more panicky if the armour moves slow because of a heavy weapon they are more likely to tense up so hard the weapon breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Up-scaling the weapon (including its weight, recoil and ammo load etc) means ups-scaling your power armor in the process - including its cost an complexity. You also rapidly reach the point where the weapon system being 'carried' by the power armor can just as easily be mounted in a normal fighting vehicle.

This means your armor has to have about the same mass as a fighting vehicle fitted with the same weapon but the vehicle will almost certainly have with a lower profile and be easier too conceal.

At the same time (if not before) you reach the point where your armor ceases to be 'worn' by the wearer and is instead 'crewed'  by an operator or operators. Unless you are talking one shot 'fire and forget' systems most large weapons need a team to operate effectively for any length of time. This means you are not 'wearing' armor anymore but instead 'operating' a two legged fighting machine. And in almost all situations such a machine would be inferior to a wheeled or tracked opponent.

Answer (score 1):

**Recoil is the problem.**

Weapons soldiers use are limited not only by the mass of the weapon, but also its recoil. See the XM109, an experimental version of the M82 which weighs only 33 lbs, but has an impractical amount of recoil - no matter how strong or weak you are, firing the weapon will just about knock you over. A strong but light suit of power armor would allow soldiers to *carry* huge weapons, but not actually *fire* them, since they still do not have sufficient mass to resist the recoil.

Weapons with large recoil must be mounted to a heavy chassis, or else the weapon will shoot itself backwards when fired - firing a tank cannon that's not mounted to something with the mass of a tank is a bad idea.

Comment: Recoil is at best an engineering problem. You can for instance, just fire something in the opposite direction simultaneously to cancel it out. Or wait and find something to brace against before firing. Or even just be knocked over... who cares if the other guy is now dead. You get up and keep going.

Comment: A soldier's ability to deal with recoil is limited by their ability to counteract the recoil. If power armor makes soldiers stronger, they are also better equipped to deal with recoil. Since bullet impact and weapon recoil scale equally (as stopping power is effectively equal to recoil, action vs reaction), that means that there is no upper limit on recoil management if you're already dealing with armor that can carry the improved weaponry. I.e. your answer would only apply if the soldier could not already wield that weapon, which makes it moot.

Comment: @JohnO This is very true, recoil can be reduced to allow for very large weapons. But a recoilless weapon will necessarily pack less punch than one that does have recoil, so at some point there's a tradeoff of power vs mobility. You can choose to give a recoilless heavy weapon to a soldier in power armor, or put an even more powerful version of that weapon with recoil on a vehicle with greater mass. Agree this isn't a hard limiting factor, but something to consider.

Comment: @NuclearWang: JohnO isn't talking about a recoilless weapon, he's talking about _managing_ the (very much existing) recoil of a weapon. Also, when you say _"or put an even more powerful version of that weapon with recoil on a vehicle with greater mass"_, since there is no significant distinction between power armor and vehicles, you're disproving your own point by arguing that a vehicle can handle recoil that a power armor supposedly couldn't. Whatever technology a vehicle is outfitted with to handle recoil, so too can a power armor be outfitted with that technology.

Comment: @Flater Being stronger doesn't make you more resistant to being knocked over. At some point, the force of recoil could exceed the force of friction from the ground, meaning no matter how strong you are, you are going to move backwards when you fire. And you are missing the crux of the distinction between power armor and vehicles - it's the difference in mass. I'm working under the assumption of a relatively lightweight power suit, not a suit of armor with mass equivalent to a tank.

Comment: @NuclearWang: You're missing the point that bigger power armor is heavier and likely has a bigger (literal) footprint, both of which tremendously increase friction. On top of that, you're still not accounting for any additional technology to further counteract or even completely negate recoil. Off the top of my head: reverse thrusters, recoil rifles, non-kinetic weaponry, or even **a kickstand** ([which cannons have had for centuries](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0002/8573/6972/products/cannon-stand-u-s-cannon-in-cradle-3_300x.jpg?v=1571710904)) would all negate your recoil-based answer.

Comment: @NuclearWang: Just look at the [recoil managing technology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBntnnCFvOk) that exists today in the absence of power armor. That gun is firing _massive_ rounds by any reasonable standard, and it's just going to increase as that soldier starts wearing better and better power armor.

Comment: @John O: Re "who cares if the other guy is now dead. You get up and keep going."  Maybe.  Or maybe while you're flat on your butt, the other guy's buddy runs up and sticks a bayonet in one of the joints of your armor :-)

Comment: @jamesqf Is there a name for the genre of science fiction where the author relies on absurd anachronisms to move his plot forward? Will the powered armor sail ships try to use their powered armor oars to break the backs of the powered armor galley slaves in the other ship with some trireme maneuiver?

Comment: @John O: I don't know if there's actually a name, but it seems fairly common, with "space navies" and plots cribbed from the likes of C. S. Forester (Horatio Hornblower) and Patrick O'Brian.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need power armour to have a man portable, shootable 50 caliber. The [gepard lynx](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBntnnCFvOk) does a great job at shorter ranges no power armour needed.

Lets assume you wanted to prevent *real* overkill - like a [30mm autocannon round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/30_mm_caliber). There's probably a few engineering constraints to consider, what static and dynamic forces involved.

Armour is static, and dosen't need you to suddenly handle a large impulsive force. A gun would. Even a way to improve punching strength would have lesser dynamic forces than a gun.

Answer (score 0):

### The answer lies in why you need power armor to begin with

If your power armor is as hard to penetrate as a tank, then you need a gun as powerful as a tank's main gun to penetrate it.  The problem is that this often means annihilating the entire area that your target is standing in as well.  But in modern warfare, infantry is not used for annihilating a target, it is made for taking and holding key infrastructure.  If you start running around with 130mm cannons inside of a command bunker or on the bridge of a starship, neither side will end the conflict in possession of the thing they wanted to take and hold, because the collateral damage would take out the thing you are fighting over to begin with.

This means your weapon designers will need to design weapons that not only can penetrate an inch of carbon nanofiber composite armor plating, but can do it without destroying everything around your target.  This is where high-tech melee weapons will come into play. If your power armor has a claw that can exert thousands of tons of crushing force, or a fusion powered plasma blade that can superheat anything it touches to a 10,000K in a fraction of a second, then you start seeing weapons that will kill through the armor without having to worry about a single missed shot bringing the whole ceiling down on your head.  Power armor infantry may still have crazy powerful cannons for when they get stuck fighting in the open, but once they have a roof over thier heads, it's time to "fix bayonetts" or whatever your future equivalent of that is.

Answer (score 0):

Thorne's answer that wielding heavier weaponry is unavoidable is correct. **However,** there can still be diminished returns.

> So, powered armor can increase punching strength but won't allow you to carry that weight. Why?

A very important distinction: I infer your interest is in limiting the damage output of the weapon, not its weight. Your question is built on the assumption that the only limiting factor in weapon output is what a soldier can carry, but you're subtly also relying on that increase in weight and power output scaling equally.

Your answer is found in making that weight/damage increase not scale evenly.

If increasing a weapon's damage output by a factor of X increases its weight by an *even bigger* factor of Y, that leads to needing a significantly stronger power armor to wield it, which in turn leads to a significant increase in defense (bigger than the damage increase of the weapon).

The logic is as follows.

> 1. I make a weapon that does X times more damage
> 2. This weapon now weighs Y times more (where X < Y)
> 3. We develop armor that is Y times stronger so it can wield this new weapon
> 4. This new armor can therefore wear armor plates that are Y times stronger
> 5. This armor's defense is Y times stronger, and since X < Y, the new weapon is less effective (against the new armor) than the old weapon was (against the old armor)

And the cycle repeats. If the weapon weight increase is not linear but exponential (for a linear damage increase in weapon damage), you can't even repeat this cycle too often because of the ludicrously strong armor you'd be required to develop just to wear it.

And that is, after all, the effect you're going for.

So while the improved damage output of weapon still increases, it doesn't increase enough to actually overcome the defense increase of the improved power armor itself.

To justify this, you simply need a civilization with better armoring skill than gunsmithing skill. Or you can rely on basic chemistry whereby the material used for armor gives you more bang for your buck than the material used for your guns.

Answer (score 0):

**Carry** bigger guns? Why not. You have the extra capacity. You will be slow but sometimes that's worthwhile.

**Fire** bigger guns? Now that's another question. A bigger gun requires more stability while firing. A human-sized platform (ie. your power armor) can only provide similar stability to a normal soldier.

One real advantage is that you can ensure that the armor assists the soldier in providing better stability, but then you get something similar to what well-trained elite soldiers can do on their own. Still better, because you now have green grunts firing on par with elite squads.

Changing posture helps with stability, but again, the same for naked and assisted soldiers. But maybe, your armor has some stability-enhancing accessories, like a third leg that unfolds from your back on demand.

Still the size of the weapons you can **fire** reliably won't be affected much, even though you can

- Fire them better than you probably could, on par with the best soldiers
- Carry a much larger ammo load without dragging yourself down, so fire a lot more bullets
- Easily carry multiple alternate weapons of similar size, expanding the types of targets and ranges you can engage (Sniper rifle + Assault rifle + Submachine gun)

If we are talking about man-portable but not man-fired weapons, like portable mortars, you sure can go bigger if needed, but usually the extra capacity is better used for extra ammunition.

Answer (score 0):

**Reduce Accuracy**

You can always say powered armor that allows great strength will reduce accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

## You can't prevent M82s from being carried, but...

You can prevent them from being useful. Invent a high-tech reactive armor that completely negates conventional weapons. Next you need a high-tech gun that can get around said armor, but doesn't work near big hunks of metal (e.g. power armor).

Answer (score 0):

The weakness of any power system is often it's controlling structure. I know there are other answers about weapon recoil, but no-one's mentioned the substantial noise and vibration that a heavy weapon tends to bring with it.
All you need is for the control systems of said power armour to be unable to resist the vibration - this would make the armour technically able to bear a heavy weapon, but rendered useless and immobile as soon as the weapon is fired. As a hint, if the armour system is a self-balancing humanoid (ie two legs, or anything else that requires a substantial balance) it will require a sensitive electric gyroscope to track it's orientation. (Admittedly you'd need a bit of license on this, as I know there are now some quite strong gyroscope systems used in military jets that can deal with vibrations of supersonic flight).

If this was the case, it would create an obvious weakness when the armour sustains a hit (unless it's being used against chemical, biological or incendiary warfare I suppose). The simple answer to that is to have flexible damping/insulation between the 'main frame' and the exoskeleton - flexible enough to absorb the shock of a hit, but also to render a heavy weapon useless if mounted on it either through inaccuracy or overall torsional weakness of the shock-absorbing system.

Answer (score 0):

### Doctrine

At the moment, two of the largest armies in the world are contesting a region called [Galwan Valley](https://www.telegraphindia.com/india/galwan-valley-buffer-zone-triggers-concern/cid/1785659).

It might surprise you to learn that neither sides' troops are carrying firearms.

Despite both sides being nuclear powers, neither wishes this fight to escalate. There have been conflicts, and there have been casualties (people beaten to death with fists).

### How Does This Apply?

Limited conflicts, where one side voluntarily shows restraint, aren't new. It could be that politically use of powered armor to "keep our boys safe", but simultaneously limiting what they can do offensively is palatable to whoever is making the decisions.

### Institutional Inerta

Doctrine, design, procurement, and training can have a long lead time. So, if a prior administration commissioned the power suit as a restrained-conflict weapon, there's now institutional inertia keeping it that way, even if the current situation is different.